# Does card.io still does not support card scanning in 64-bit Android even on card.io 5.0.1?

Tags: card.io

The card.io release note for 5.0.1 mentions "Fix issue where arm64-v8a devices were not allowing the scanning of devices". I noticed that the 5.0.1 card.io distribution does not contain any 64-bit libraries at all. So I wanted to get confirmation that card.io still does not support card scanning in 64-bit Android even on card.io 5.0.1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks if an external library does or does not support something at a particular point in time. It is subject to rot, and the authoritative answer is unlikely to come from StackOverflow to begin with.

Comment: There are about 120 questions tagged "card.io" as this one is.

Comment: That may be, but (most of) those questions deal with it's usage, not with whether it supports x feature. Getting the confirmation you are asking for, for this point in time, is best done directly with the makers.

Comment: The makers of card.io mention only two ways to send them feedback or support requests. One is to tweet @cardio, and the other is to "check and post to the Stack Overflow card.io tag."

Comment: Well, I trust the moderators of SO will ensure this remains open if SO is a valid support site for `card.io`. However, I'm not sure that `card.io` gets to make that decision unilaterally. *shrug*

Comment: Those of us who support `card.io` love SO!  Keep the questions coming here and the relevant GitHub repos.

Answer (score 0):

ARM_64 *should* be supported on Android. But I did look at the AAR and you are correct that those libs seem to be missing, so it is possible that there is a build bug.

If you've tested on an ARM_64 device and found that the scanning does not work, it would be helpful if you [open an issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues) and include:

- The specific device model
- Relevant logcat entries with JNI load errors or card.io messages.

Comment: To add to this, if an app contains other 64-bit libraries, the app will not be able to scan cards.  Only if the app has no other 64-bit libs will it work, as the processors fall-back to 32-bit libs if no 64-bit libs are present.  We have yet to add official 64-bit support to card.io.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer: 64-bit is now supported as of release [5.1.0](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/releases).